# Display Data from Json Array Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

I am trying to display data from JSON array in a table using following code. But all data is displayed in a single row. It should be displayed as each record in each row with grey color for Even and White for odd. But I am making some mistake I am not able to identify it.

CSS Style:

```
table,td  {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    width:1047px;
    height: 64px;
    left:16px;
    position:relative;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

My View (It is a partial view which is displayed from index.html):

      <h1 id="title">Shuttle Schedule</h1>
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="25" style="margin-top:-118px">
            <thead  align="center">
                <th ng-repeat="row in module.csvInput">{{row.label}}</th>
                <th ng-repeat="row in module.csvInput">{{row.label}}</th>

            </thead>
            <tr align="center" >
                <td ng-repeat="row in module.csvInput" >
                    <div ng-repeat="(id, time) in row.times" ng-if="id <= 8">
                    {{time}}
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="row in module.csvInput">
                    <div ng-repeat="(id, time) in row.times" ng-if="id > 8">
                        {{time}}
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3 class="noservice">No Service 1:20pm to 2:00pm<br> Driver can make additional runs beyond this schedule if needed.<br>
            D1 is 8910 Ridgeline Blvd. D4 is 8744 Lucent Blvd.</h3>
    </div>
```

My JSON's Snippet:

```
{
  "modules": [


    {
      "title": "Shuttle Schedule",
      "feature": "shuttle",
      "order": 4,
      "csvInput": [
        {
          "label": "D1 PickUp",
          "times": [
            "8:00 AM",
            "8:30 AM",
            "9:00 AM",
            "9:30 AM",
            "10:00 AM",
            "10:30 AM",
            "11:00 AM",
            "11:30 AM",
            "12:00 PM",
            "12:30 PM",
            "1:30 PM"
          ]
        },
        {
        "label": "D4 PickUp",
        "times": [
          "7:50 AM",
          "8:20 AM",
          "8:50 AM",
          "9:20 AM",
          "9:50 AM",
          "10:20 AM",
          "10:50 AM",
          "11:20 AM",
          "11:50 AM",
          "12:20 PM",
          "12:50 PM",
          "1:10 PM"
        ]
      }
      ],
      "filter": null,
      "icon": "media/shuttle.svg"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "buildings": 2,
    "floor": 4,
    "timeout": "120 (in seconds)",
    "cssOverride": "custom.css",
    "kiosk_coords": "200,200"
  }
}
```

My output:
[image: My out put in a single cell in a table]

Desired Styling output :
[image: I am trying to achieve this styling and data in separate rows]

Comment: Nothing is displayed if I do like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should put ng-repeat on tr tag not on td tag first. 
So it should be something like :

```
<table> <tr ng-repeat="entity in list"><td>{{entity.lable}}</td> 
<td ng-repeat="time in entity.times">{{time}}</td></tr></table>
```

EDIT : 
if you want your data to look in html like : 
entity.label : entity.time
entity.label : entity.time 
...

Then you should probably do this :

```
<table> <div ng-repeat="entity in list"><tr ng-repeat="time in entity.times><td ng-class-odd="'grey'" ng-class-even="'white'">{{entity.lable}}</td> 
<td ng-class-odd="'grey'" ng-class-even="'white'">{{time}}</td></tr></div></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response. But Nothing is displayed if try it. It displays everything in a single row.

Comment: desired output given for reference doesn't match the data you have provided. Please show the desired output according to the data and I could help you out.

Comment: Desired out put will be similar to the second Image styling wise. Data in D1 and D4 Pickup will be displayed in each rows differently rather than all data in a single row.

Comment: Please see the edit section... And rest styling you can always do using ngClassOdd and ngClassEven directives...

Comment: I know styling can be done on odd and even rows. It's already applied. But the problem is that all data is displayed in the 2 td of same tr. Rather than 2 td in each different rows(tr).

Comment: Please use the code snippet in edit section , make two classes with name grey and white for the corresponding background of row and see if things works...

Comment: Your `<div>` should be a `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unroll the data to match the way you want them to be displayed

```
$scope.module = data.modules[0];
var csvInput = $scope.module.csvInput;
$scope.headers = csvInput.map(x => x.label );
var rows = csvInput.map(x => x.times.slice(0, 8)).concat(csvInput.map(x => x.times.slice(8)));
var n = Math.max.apply(null, rows.map(x => x.length));
$scope.rows = [];
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  $scope.rows[i] = rows.map(x => x[i]);
}
```

And display that data

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="25" style="margin-top:-118px">
  <thead align="center">
    <th ng-repeat="row in headers">{{row}}</th>
    <th ng-repeat="row in headers">{{row}}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/r0005a1t/